# convert from json to post data by python

Tags: python, json, post, decoder

given json `{"foo":"bazz","1":2}`

I want to convert it to POST data :

```
"foo"="bazz";"1"=2;
```

(the data format in case it were posted from html form)

is there any exist `decoder` for `json>> POST data`? if no, does next script will do it as well?

```
json_body = {"foo":"bazz","1":2}
data = ''
for key, value in json_body.items():
    data += '"{key}"={value};'.format(key=key, value=value)
print data
>> "foo"="bazz";"1"=2;
```

thanks

Comment: The format you specify is *not* POST data (x-www-form-urlencoded); what format is that supposed to be?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`urllib.parse.urlencode`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode):

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode

data = urlencode(json_body)
```

This produces `x-www-form-urlencoded` data, which is the default mime-type used by browsers when POST-ing HTML forms.